# Package caption error when using rotating

Tags: captions, packages, subcaption

When I try to include both `\usepackage{rotating}` and `\usepackage{caption}` or `\usepackage{subcaption}` in my preamble, I get the following error:

```
Package caption Error: For a successful cooperation we need at least version(caption) is available.
```

When I use only the caption package, it works fine. I managed to get things done without using rotating, but I was wondering if there's anyone that had a similar problem and could find a solution for this? I believe that rotating is no longer updated and that caused this issue. In that case, is there any replacement for this package?

Thanks.

Edit: I'm using TeXstudio and MiKTeX

(Though I don't think it's necessary, here's a WME)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
  This article is just a test
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think those packages are conflicting. I checked and it was fine for me.

Comment: Your `MWE` working fine for me, hope it may related with version issue, please update the latest version and check...

Comment: It may be due to the old version of your packages.

Comment: I'm currently updating all the packages, and as soon as I can, I'll check to see if everything is ok. Thank you all for your help

Comment: Still getting the same error... I'm using TeXstudio and MikTex on Windows, is there anything I should know that could cause this error?

Comment: Your example works fine in miktex. Update miktex in user *and* admin mode. If the error persists show the log-file.

Comment: The `caption` package needs at least version "1995/08/22 v2.10" of the `rotating` package, so it seems that you have loaded an older one. Maybe there is an old/obsolete version of the `rotating` package in your document folder? Check the log file of your document to see from what directory location the `rotating` package is actually loaded.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Even though I had updated the files with MikTeX, it was still using version "1994/04/15" . Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Just to clarify everything: I've downloaded my university monography LaTeX template, and within the files, there was a "rotating.sty" that I didn't see, which was a 1994 version. I'm reporting this to whoever is responsible for maintaining the template to update the version. Thank you for all of you who helped me get to this error!